# Any way to eliminate "Access my basic information" from Facebook Connect?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook connect to let users import some photos.

The only permission I've requested is `user_photos` but facebook adds the default one `Access my basic information` at the top which says they are also giving me access to their name, list of friends, and "any other information I've shared with everyone".

I really only want access to the photos, and I think the "basic information" box will scare off some users who don't want to give access to this.  Is there any way to get rid of that part?

[image]

Comment: Hey Brian, hav u done this with graph api, or some older one, actually i hav the same thing, i have to fetch out the user pics, i have completed this with new grpah api, but it has some issues, actually i hav one old facebook-actonscript api(working),that onle asks for "Access my basic info" but i m not getting how to pass the "user_photos" permission in to that one,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't exclude it because, it is the basic information of the user that is needed by an application to work and as you said yourself, a user will only share "any other information I've shared with everyone".

The information you'll get with the basic information is already shared by the user to everyone else.

Unless you believe that you are not part of that everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can have whatever is public.

Comment: Your answer is quite terse. A little bit more details would be appreciated. Thanks!